Is the following infinitesimal change in von Neumann entropy correct?
Let $\rho_t$ be the time-dependent density matrix and
$S(\rho_t)=-\operatorname{tr}(\rho_t \ln\rho_t)$ be the von Neumann entropy.
When $\rho_t$ obeys the following stochastic equation
$d\rho_t =f(\rho_t)dt+g(\rho_t)dW_t$, is the infinitesimal change of $S(\rho_t)$ correct as follows?
$dS(\rho_t)=-\operatorname{tr}(d\rho_t\ln\rho_t)-\operatorname{tr}((d\rho_t)^2\rho^{-1}_t)$

$W_t$ is the  Wiener process and the above expression $d\rho_t=...$ is the Ito formula, not Stratonovich one.

Shouldn't it be
$$\large{
\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}
\def\tr{{\sf tr}}
dS ,=, -\tr(d\rho_t,\ln\rho_t) - \tr(d\rho_t)
}$$

Sorry, I forgot to write the condition $tr(d\rho_t)=0$.  I think $dS=-tr(d\rho\ln\rho)-tr(\rho \rho^{-1}d\rho)-tr(d\rho \rho^{-1}d\rho)$.
